# Copying data with SSIS without recreating the tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I want to copy data from database A to database B.

I created a saved SSIS package successfully and data was indeed copied from A to B. Now I want to automate the process but when I'm launching the saved .dtsx file I get this error:

```
"Error: Executing the query 
    "CREATE TABLE ... failed with the following error: 
       "There is already an object named ... in the database"..."
```

Seems like SSIS is trying to create the table again. How do I set SSIS to copy the data only, without recreating the table?

Ta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either directly edit the package in BIDS and take out the CREATE TABLE part, or you can use the wizard to make a new package that uses the existing table rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for (even though it's an bit of an 'over kill' to download a 809mb file just to change a line of code...)